# NextJS breaking when route is rerendered for the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to fetch data from the local api in NextJS 13, but when I run the webpage for the second time (going to a different route and then going back), it gives this error. Does anyone know why?

The error I get:

[image]

`page.tsx`:

```
export function DefaultSideBar() {
  return (
    <SideBar>
      <Logo></Logo>
      <SideOption src={AHlogo} title="Auction Browser"></SideOption>
    </SideBar>
  )
}

export default function Home() {
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <DefaultSideBar></DefaultSideBar>
        <MainPage disabled={false}></MainPage>
      </div>
    </>
    
  )
}
```

`<Sidebar />` definition:

```
export function SideBar(props: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.sidebar}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

MainPage and News:

```
export function MainPage(props: {disabled: boolean}) {
    return (
        <div className={styles["page"]}>
            <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
            <hr />
            <h2>News</h2>
            <News></News>
        </div >
    )
}
```

```
export function News() {
    'use client';

    let [outelems, setOutelems] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([])
    let dataref = useRef<NewsPanel[]>()
    dataref.current = use (getNewsData());
    useMemo(() => {
        console.log("ran")
        setOutelems((dataref.current ?? []).map(
            (d, index) => {
    
                return (
                    <a key={index} href={`/news/${index}`} className={styles["news-panel"]}>
                        <div >
                            <h3 className={styles["news-title"]}>{d.title}</h3>
                            <p className={styles["news-desc"]}><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: formatDesc(d.description).split(" ").slice(0, 22).join(" ") + (formatDesc(d.description).split(" ").length > 22 ? "..." : "")}}></span> </p>
                            <p className={styles["news-time"]}>{timeConverter(parseInt(d.creation_date.toString()))}</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    
                )
    
            }
        ).reverse())
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={styles["news-scroll"]}>
            {outelems}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `SideBar` import matches the path of the component's file location.

Comment: @juliomalves It is imported in the correct location, sorry for the confusion because I didn't include that.